# Is this a Fourier series? What is its sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the sum of this series, I cannot identify what kind it is or how to start. Any help is appreciated

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!}\right)$$

Comment: What is the origin of this question? Did you just think of this series or encountered it somewhere?

Comment: How can I calculate the real part of $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{r i \theta}}{r!} $?

Answer (score 3):

Your series is the real part of:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\left(e^{ix}\right)^n}{n!} = e^{\cos x+i\sin x} = e^{\cos x}\left(\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x)\right)$$
hence it equals:
$$\color{red}{e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Combine $\cos(u)=(e^{iu}+e^{-iu})/2$ with the Taylor series $\displaystyle \exp(v)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{v^n}{n!}$.

You should end up with exponentials *of* exponentials. If you want you can go further and rewrite the expression without the imaginary unit $i$, using $e^{a+bi}=e^a(\cos(b)+\sin(b)i)$.